# Android Licensing Error 561 (0x231)

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have some applications that were transferred from another company to ours. We have had google move them to our Publisher Account. However I am trying to verify the Licensing and can only get Don't Allow with an error of 561.

I have done a lot of licensed apps and have checked permissions, PUBLIC_KEY, Test Accounts, to whole thing. I have checked versions, and tried testing the app signed and unsigned. No luck it always gives an error 561.

I cannot find anything about an error 561, does anyone know what this code means?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?
I too had apps transferred from one account to another ... Is that the reason ? I noticed that the Public key has not changed after the transfer ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Licensing Error 561 -This application is not licensed. Please purchase it from Android Market](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29951297/android-licensing-error-561-this-application-is-not-licensed-please-purchase-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the Method `void processServerResponse(int response, ResponseData rawData);` in the interface `com.google.android.vending.licensing.Policy` 
561 is the same as 0x231 which is definde in the interafce as NOT_LICENSED.
So there is an error with your license and you should check in the rawData to see why.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, I spent a whole day to get rid of it. In my case, the problem was due to **network security**. I tried it with the different network (Personal hotspot network). It worked well.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is maybe for anyone because it's late.

Make sure that you add the `CHECK_LICENCE` permission in the Manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />`

and make sure you upload the app to the store for testing.